# How can I pass multiple values in a function parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a program that calculates compound interest with 3 different lists. The first item in each list are the variables needed in the formula A=P(1+r)^n. These are the instructions.

```
Albert Einstein once said “compound interest” is man’s greatest invention. Use the equation A=P(1+r) n
,
where P is the amount invested, r is the annual percentage rate (as a decimal 5.0%=0.050) and n is the
number of years of the investment.
Input: 3 lists representing investments, rates, and terms
investment = [10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 1.00]
rate = [5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 50.00]
term = [20, 40, 20, 40, 40]
Output: Show the final investment.
$26532.98
$70399.89
$67275.00
$452592.56
$11057332.32
```

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
P = [10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 10000.00, 1.00]
r = [5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 50.00]
n = [20, 40, 20, 40, 40]

# A=P(1+r)
def formula(principal,rate,years):
    body = principal*pow((1 + rate),years)
    print "%.2f" %(body)
def sort(lst):
    spot = 0
    for item in lst:
        item /= 100
        lst[spot] = item
        spot += 1

input = map(list,zip(P,r,n))
sort(r)
for i in input:
    for j in i:
        formula()
```

I firstly define a function to calculate the compound interest, then I define a function to convert the rates to the proper format. Then using map (which im not completely familiar with)I separate the first item of each list into a tuple within the new input list. What i am trying to do is find a way to input the three items within in the tuple into principle, rate and years in the formula function. 
I am open to critiquing, and advice. I am still fairly new with programming in general. 
Thank you.

Comment: Judging by the title I have a feeling that your actual question could and should be decoupled from your specific code, with a clear, concise [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and without all the boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you should `return` something from your `formula`, that is, your calculation:

```
def formula(principal,rate,years):
    return principal*pow((1 + rate),years) #return this result
```

then you can use the `return` value from the `formula` - be it for printing or any other use for further calculation.

Also, since you have the same amount of items in your three lists, why not just using `range(len(p))` to iterate over them?

```
for x in range(len(p)):
    print(formula(p[x],r[x],n[x]))
```

`x in range(len(p))` will generate iteration with x value:

```
0, 1, ..., len(p) - 1 # in your case, len(p) = 5, thus x ranges from 0 to 4
```

And `p[x]` is the way you say you want to get `x-th-indexed` element from `p`. Putting it you your context you will get combination like this:

```
when x=   principal   rate   years
----------------------------------
  0       10000.00     5.0     20
  1       10000.00     5.0     40
  2       10000.00    10.0     20
  3       10000.00    10.0     40
  4           1.00    50.0     40
```

This way, you do not need to use `tuple`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the feedback. It works! :) On another note, how can i format the outputs to round to the hundredths place if I'm using return? I used round that worked, but when the result was 0 even it only displayed one zero. I'm really OCD about that stuff so I'm trying to use the %.2f somehow. So the answer is 67284.0, and i want it to look like 67284.00

Comment: @avbirm check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850378/limited-digits-with-str-format-and-then-only-when-they-matter) recent post. Seems like what you want. :)