# Limited digits with str.format(), and then only when they matter

Tags: python

If we're printing a dollar amount, we usually want to always display two decimal digits.

```
cost1, cost2 = 123.456890123456789, 357.000
print '{c1:.2f}  {c2:.2f}'.format(c1=cost1, c2=cost2)
```

shows

```
123.46  357.00
```

But on other occasions we'd like to print the fractions only if they matter. If the two numbers above were volume, for instance, we may prefer to display

```
123.45 gal. 357 gal.
```

Can this be obtained directly with `format`?

Comment: And what does "if they matter" mean? These are called significant digits - 123.46 has 5 significant digits, 2 after decimal point, so does 357.00. If they weren't significant, you wouldn't show 123.46 either ;)

Comment: Was it intentionally truncated, rather than rounded, to `123.45` in the desired output? Or is `123.46` acceptable/intended there?

Comment: Second @ jonrsharpe.  the answer is No for formatting. Not unless you put a checking logic on them. 

This looks like "I can do this in Excel formatting macro and how I can do this in python".    You need to create a function to "round" the number when the trailing is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) Python Docs describe the `%g` format which truncates trailing zeros.

```
>>> print "%g gallons" % (123.45)
123.45 gallons

>>> print "%g gallons" % (357)
357 gallons

>>> print "%g gallons" % (357.0)
357 gallons
```

Or using [Python 3 string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
>>> print "{:g} gal {:g} gal".format(123.45, 357.0)
123.45 gal 357 gal
```

The `g` formatter is unintuitive but you can get some interesting results by setting the [precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
>>> print "{:g} gal {:.3g} gal {:.4g} gal {:.5g} gal {:.6g} gal {:.7g} gal".format(*([123.456789] * 6))
123.457 gal 123 gal 123.5 gal 123.46 gal 123.457 gal 123.4568 gal
```

Note that in this case setting precision to `.5` achieves the desired result of 2 decimal places.

Of course you could combine this with `f` floating point formatter first to get whatever you wanted.

Comment: But this doesn't necessarily give 2dp; `'{:g}'.format(123.456890123456789)` is `'123.457'`. Also `str.format` isn't just for 3.x (and vice versa).

Comment: The Python 3 string formatting has been available from Python 2.6 and above.